# How to allow facebook login from iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe, callback

My app is widget that is embedded into other website but the one of the most important features is login with facebook.

But now I have a problem.
I have `iframe` tag but also inside iframe I have:

```
<a href="http://roomtobid.com/social/login/redirect/facebook" class="btn btn-info btn-lg col-md-12" >Facebook</a>
```

and now when I try to click and login, just nothing happened.
Also when I look at browser console I get error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=17499948800008…m5xN3sZ3hrPQWQ44FYQPR1yPpsDwLuvoTP9jtZq6%23_%3D_&display=page&locale=sr_RS'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

How I can solve my problem?

Also I try to add `target="_top"` at `<a>` tag and that work but then send me to first to facebook and then as callback to original domain not back to iFrame.

Is there any way to solve this?

I see that zopim chat allow their visitors to login with facebook, but their facebook login is opened into new small window.

Comment: Use a popup instead of iframe.

Comment: But yes, iframe is inside popup window...

Comment: So create a popup without an iframe.

Comment: I cant, my core widget - app is created on my own server so I distrubute my app as widget for other webistes (like zopim chat and similar...)

Comment: So maybe use JavaScript: `window.parent.location.href = "facebook address"`.

Comment: Post a [mcve], without more code it's hard to guess what could cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> but then send me to first to facebook and then as callback to original domain not back to iFrame

Of course not.

It only redirects back to the address specified as `redirect_uri` - and that address has to match the app domain, resp. be specified as a valid OAuth redirect URI in the app settings.

The only thing you can possibly do, is put the URL of the page that the iframe is on, into your apps callback URL as a *parameter* - so that your app can redirect back there, after Facebook login has redirected back to your app.

You could also try and put it into the session - but that might be problematic if the user has multiple pages opened that embed your widget, plus session cookies and 3rd-party cookie blocking easily cause additional trouble.

And that still leaves your with the problem of getting the "parent" page's URL in the first place. The parent page would have to explicitly transport that information to your widget in the first place, like via a GET parameter that they append to your widget's address in the iframe `src`. (Either the URL directly, or maybe some sort of client identifier, that you then look up in your database.)

Comment: but with zopim chat user can sign in with facebook easily, when click on sign in into widget then open new facebook smaller window and when auth is over you just see that you are signed into zopim chat